# Iterate through HashMap and sum key values that match same key

Tags: java

I have a set of values in a text file which I'm reading from. How can I store those values in a HashMap or List and compare them to later sum them?
Ex:

```
"UniqueKey1" "Tom" 1
"UniqueKey2" "Tom" 2
"UniqueKey3" "Alex" 4
```

So since I have two Tom, I'd like to sum their values, which is 3

This is what I've tried:

```
Double counter = 0.0;
Map<String, Double> dataMap = new HashMap<String, Double>();
Iterator iterator = dataMap.entrySet().iterator();
List<String> matchingKeys = new ArrayList<>();
String dataFile = propertiesGetterUtilObj.getNewFilePath();
Path path = Paths.get(dataFile);

if(path != null) { 
    BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path);
    String lineValue = null;
          while ((lineValue = reader.readLine()) != null) {                                     
                String tradeId = token[0];
                String date = token[1];
                Double price = Double.parseDouble(token[2]);
                dataMap.put(date, price);

                }
```

Here I'm trying to map the date to be the key and what I want to sum which is the prices

how do I get those values added to the map and sum those who have the same key values and store it?

The point is that I will have unique values and repeated dates, then I would sum the values of those dates

Thank you

Comment: I'll post it in a sec

Comment: I would create an object that has `String` name and `int` value. You can then sum values with the same name.

Comment: @Hulk See the code change please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long approach compared to other answers. You could create an object. Then create a list of those objects and use a stream to map and sum their values.

> Main

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class JavaApplication24 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        List<PersonValueObject> data = new ArrayList();
        data.add(new PersonValueObject("Tom", 1));
        data.add(new PersonValueObject("Tom", 2));
        data.add(new PersonValueObject("Alex", 4));

        Map<String, Integer> result = data.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(PersonValueObject::getName, Collectors.summingInt(PersonValueObject::getValue)));

        for (Map.Entry<String,Integer> entry : result.entrySet())  
            System.out.println("Key = " + entry.getKey() + 
                             ", Value = " + entry.getValue()); 
    }         
}
```

> Object

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package javaapplication24;

/**
 *
 * @author blj0011
 */
public class PersonValueObject {
    private String name;
    private int value;

    public PersonValueObject(String name, int value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }


}
```

> Output

```
run:
Key = Alex, Value = 4
Key = Tom, Value = 3
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot meaningfully "Iterate through [a] HashMap and sum key values that match [the] same key" because a `Map` cannot contain multiple mappings for the same key.  You can, however, maintain a running sum of the values for each key as you add mappings.

There are multiple ways to do this, but one of the easier ones is to use [`HashMap.merge()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#merge(K,V,java.util.function.BiFunction)) to handle both adding new mappings and updating existing ones, as appropriate:

```
Map<String, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<>();

// ...
String key = "Tom";
int value = 4;

myMap.merge(key, value, (v1, v2) -> { return v1 + v2; });
```

Comment: This seems like a good solution, I forgot about the unique value. I'm trying it now, thanks

Comment: One question, what If I have 3 values? For example, I have a unique key, then the name "Tom" and then the value. Because in your answer you are assuming that "Tom" would not be repeated, but the point is that I will have unique values and repeated dates, then I would sum the values of those dates

Comment: @Spyky, it is extremely poor form to modify your question after it has answers, especially in a way that affects the applicability of the answers.  This is what you have done.  The correct way forward from here would be for you to roll back the edit, and pose a new question with your alternative requirements.

Comment: I had the wrong explanation in it, the person answering was clearly not understanding

Comment: @spyky, "I had the wrong explanation" == "I asked a different question than I meant to ask".  It remains poor form to modify the question after you have answers, even if it is only by the answers that you recognized the problem with the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a class to map multiple key values if John's answer isn't what you are interested in. It would look something like this:

```
public class MultiMap<T> {
Map<Object, ArrayList<T>> multiMap = new HashMap<Object, ArrayList<T>>();

public void store(Object key, T value){
   if(!multiMap.containsKey(key)){
      multiMap.put(key, new ArrayList<T>());
   }
   multiMap.get(key).add(value);
   }

public ArrayList<T> get(Object key){
    return multiMap.get(key);
   }
}
```

Where you map multiple values per a key within a list that you can then iterate through.

Comment: That was a little advanced for me, so that would store the values of the same key in 1 object in 1 array list?

Comment: Yep! You see, a normal Map for java will store one key per value, so if you have a key called "Fruit" and it already has the value 40 mapped to it, when you go to put another value for the key "Fruit", it will overwrite the 40 and put the new value instead. So a trick that I use often is that I've created a class that maps a key to a list. By doing this, I can map multiple values per a key instead of just one. Instead of "Fruit" = 40, it becomes "Fruit" = {40, 20, 30, etc.}